# When using the 'longtable' package, how can I have the table title on the second page indicate that it's a continuation from the previous page?

Tags: tables, longtable

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}              % Longtable package
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}   % Margins
\usepackage{booktabs}               % Nicer horizontal lines

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ l l }
\caption{Heading} \\ \toprule       % toprule, midrule, and bottomrule are the horizontal lines
Left Heading & Right Heading \\ \midrule
\endhead
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\ \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The above code produces the following:
[image: First page.] [image: Second page.]

But this is what I want on the second page (this is obviously a product of MS Paint, but please bear with me):
[image: This is what I want]!

So, how would I do this?

Comment: You have to define a first head. Just have a look into the documentation please.

Comment: @Christian blame the twisted logic of the package author.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah, I know it's your package. Kinda hoped you wouldn't find this thread ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\endfirsthead` for the first heading and `\endhead` for all the other pages.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}              % Longtable package
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}   % Margins
\usepackage{booktabs}               % Nicer horizontal lines

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ l l }
\caption{Heading} \\ \toprule       % toprule, midrule, and bottomrule are the horizontal lines
Left Heading & Right Heading \\ \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{Heading (cont.)} \\ \toprule       % toprule, midrule, and bottomrule are the horizontal lines
Left Heading & Right Heading \\ \midrule
\endhead
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\
Left cell & Right cell \\ \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: +1 for having read my extensive and lucid documentation:-)